# Split single list elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of data that I am trying to manipulate.

```
initial_list = [333322222111111, 555000033311123, 666333312466332]
```

I want to put each element into a new list and then split them further so my new list would be:

```
new_list = [[333,22222111111], [555, 000033311123], [666,333312466332]]
```

I have done the following:

```
new_list = [[] for i in range(0, len(initial_list))]
```

This gives me:`new_list = [[], [], []]`

```
for i in range(0, len(new_list)):
    new_list[i].append(initial_list[i])
```

This has given me

```
[[333322222111111], [555000033311123], [666333312466332]]
```

I'm now stuck how to split each nested list... The .split method only works with strings.. The first 3 values within each list need to be cut off.. Ideally I'd even want to split the other part into further even chunks

Any advice on what direction to go would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Assume all your value are of the same length. The following code will output what you want.

```
>>> a = [333322222111111, 555000033311123, 666333312466332]
>>> [ [i/10**12, i%10**12] for i in a]
[[333, 322222111111], [555, 33311123], [666, 333312466332]]
```

Some resources about the answer: [List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, Just use the slicing of string,

```
In [18]: print [map(int,[i[:3],i[3:]]) for i in map(str,initial_list)]

[[333, 322222111111], [555, 33311123], [666, 333312466332]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
initial_list = [333322222111111, 555000033311123, 666333312466332]
new_list =[]
for i in initial_list:
    i=str(i)
    new_list.append([int(i[0:3]),int(i[3:])])
print new_list
```

Output:

```
[[333, 322222111111], [555, 33311123], [666, 333312466332]]
```

As per your doubt(comment section) of getting output in below new format:

```
output: [[333, 3222, 2211, 1111], [555, 0, 3331, 1123], [666, 3333, 1246, 6332]]
```

Here is the code:

```
initial_list = [333322222111111, 555000033311123, 666333312466332]
new_list =[]
for i in initial_list:
    i=str(i)
    temp_list=[]
    temp_list.append(int(i[0:3]))
    jump=4
    for j in range(3,len(i),jump):
        temp_list.append(int(i[j:j+jump]))
    new_list.append(temp_list)
print new_list
```

Comment: I like this approach.... and If I wanted to split index 1 within each list then into every 4 how could I do this? i.e [333, 3222, 2211, 1111].

Comment: So, if given input is,                                                                         
    initial_list = [333322222111111, 555000033311123, 666333312466332]. What output you expect ?

Comment: I would want output_list = [[333, 3222, 2211, 1111], [555, 0000, 3331, 1123]], [666, 3333, 1246, 6332]].... The first index of each list being 3 chars and the rest all being divided into sets of 4..

Comment: @arsenal88, edited my post. Please check.                                                             `output: [[333, 3222, 2211, 1111], [555, 0, 3331, 1123], [666, 3333, 1246, 6332]]`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 a = [333322222111111, 555000033311123, 666333312466332]
 mylst = [divmod(i,10**12) for i in a]
 print mylst
```

output:

```
[[333, 322222111111],  [555, 33311123],[666, 333312466332]]
```